# Temporary add node to XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I need to create a temporary root node for an XDocument, but i need to do this without destroying the reference.

So the should still work

```
XElement x = doc.Root.FirstNode;
// Inset magic here that adds the "MyTempRoot"
Console.WriteLine(x.Name); // This should still work
```

Example

```
<elements>
    <item />
    <item />
    <item />
</elements>
```

To

```
<MyTempRoot>
    <elements>
        <item />
        <item />
        <item />
    </elements>
</MyTempRoot>
```

Comment: If you want to use the same object, the only way is to add the temporary node and then remove it. Or, copy the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be sufficient

```
doc.Root.ReplaceWith(new XElement("MyTempRoot", doc.Root));
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way

```
private void AddTempRoot(XDocument doc)
{
    XElement tempRoot= new XElement("MyTempRood");
    var elements = doc.Elements();
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        element.Remove();
        tempRoot.Add(element);
    }
    doc.Add(tempRoot);
}

private void RemoveTempRoot(XDocument doc)
{
    var tempRoot = doc.Root;
    tempRoot.Remove();
    var elements = tempRoot.Elements();
    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        element.Remove();
        doc.Add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that by copying elements this way you'll loose XML comments; not sure if it's applicable here, but probably worth mentioning.